# Drone/Quadcopter sim that allows custom building/editing of (large) quads?

Tags: building, simulators

For some reason, there seems to be a huge gap when it comes to medium-sized video platform drones, such as one I'm planning to build. I don't have any experience with acro flying, so while pretty much any popular drone sim would help tremendously, I'd like to get a feel for how my much larger drone will fly (in acro) without risking a crash.

I'm looking for a simulator that will specifically let me replicate and practice on my real drone as closely as possible. It has 15" props, 600kv 4108 motors, 680mm (ZD680) frame, and will use a 4s. I've yet to see a single drone like this in a simulator. I guess what I'm looking is something where you could actually plan out a build accurately in software without purchasing a single part.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about a simulator. However, often in motor's datasheets it will say power consumption and expected thrust under different conditions. Keep in mind that things aren't 100% efficient and you need to multiply the number for one motor by 4, for 4 motors.

For example, here is a motor from sunnysky, and you can follow the chart for prop size, thrust, power, etc. [image]